# How do I construct the proper before_destroy in model in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following which deletes a bin and everything related to it. It's great and functions;

**MODEL BIN**

```
class Bin < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :savedtweets, :dependent => :destroy
    before_destroy :mod_newtweets

    def mod_newtweets
        Newtweet.where(:tweet_id => @bin.savedtweets.pluck(:tweet_id)).update_all(:status => 'new')
    end
end
```

However, it destroys a bin, deletes everything but doesn't run :mod_newtweets to update my other table and its column.

If I put this in the controller it works fine;

```
Newtweet.where(:tweet_id => @bin.savedtweets.pluck(:tweet_id)).update_all(:status => 'new')
```

I thought I've got everything done right.

Comment: Can you verify that the before_destroy is actually called (put a break point in the mod_newtweets)?
Also is it possible that the savedtweets are destoyed before the before_destroy is called? Can you try removing ":dependent => :destroy" and try it?

Comment: What are the benefits putting the Newtweet.where in model compare to controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your method with:

```
def mod_newtweets
    Newtweet.where(:tweet_id => savedtweets.pluck(:tweet_id)).update_all(:status => 'new')
end
```

You are using `@bin.savedtweets` in your model while you have not defined @bin anywhere. as it is an instance method you can use either `self.savedtweets` or only `savedtweets` to call the savedtweets method on current instance of Bin model.